# Android Studio - Getting numbers instead of HTML Content

Tags: java, android, html, android-studio, android-download-manager

I'm beginner in coding and Java. I'm going through an Udemy Course by Codestars and I stuck in a project. I need to download the HTML content of the web page, http://www.posh24.se/kandisar, but I keep getting random numbers instead of HTML content. I tried with some other websites too, but I keep having same problem. Here is my Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();
            while (data != -1) {

                char current = (char) data;
                result += data;
                data = reader.read();
            }

            return result;

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    String result = null;
    try {
        result = task.execute("http://posh24.se/kandisar").get();
        Log.i("Content", result);

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is sample of my Logcat:

`2020-01-22 15:37:14.409 1744-1753/? I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 43928(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 14(296KB) LOS objects, 36% free, 10MB/16MB, paused 1.437ms total 144.445ms
2020-01-22 15:37:22.058 3937-3962/com.example.guessthecelebrity I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 81(32KB) AllocSpace objects, 75(12MB) LOS objects, 24% free, 18MB/24MB, paused 1.867ms total 105.900ms
2020-01-22 15:37:23.047 3937-3962/com.example.guessthecelebrity I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 75(32KB) AllocSpace objects, 75(12MB) LOS objects, 46% free, 7MB/13MB, paused 2.252ms total 117.104ms
2020-01-22 15:37:24.447 3937-3962/com.example.guessthecelebrity I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 79(32KB) AllocSpace objects, 72(12MB) LOS objects, 44% free, 7MB/13MB, paused 6.058ms total 54.727ms
2020-01-22 15:37:25.371 3937-3962/com.example.guessthecelebrity I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 72(31KB) AllocSpace objects, 69(12MB) LOS objects, 42% free, 8MB/14MB, paused 2.541ms total 109.323ms
2020-01-22 15:37:29.439 3937-3937/com.example.guessthecelebrity I/Content: 60336879678489806932104116109108621060104116109108621060104101971006210101010101010101010101060116105116108101628411111211232494848327522811010010511597114324532801111151045052604711610511610810162106098971151013210411410110261344734476210960109101116973299104971141151011166134117116455634626047109101116976210960109101116973210411611611245101113117105118613467111110116101110116458412111210134329911111011610111011661341161011201164710411610910859329910497114115101116611171161024556346260471091011169762109601091011169732110971091016134114111981111161153432991111101161011101166134105110100101120441021111081081111193462604710910111697621096010910111697321109710910161341181051011191121111141163432991111101161011101166134119105100116104611001011181059910145119105100116104443210511010511610597108451159997108101614946483462604710910111697621096010910111697321109710910161349711211210810145109111981051081014511910198459711211245116105116108101343299111110116101110116613480111115104505234626047109101116976210960109101116973211097109101613410311111110310810145115105116101451181011141051021059997116105111110343299111110116101110116613453998911910911770655610382111765777746657110109118115487056888448112837010654901048912156828710770523462604710910111697621096010910111697321109710910161341001011159911410511211610511111034329911111011610111011661347610511511697322461181011143211611111211232494848321072281101001051159711432106117115116321101173332861053210810511511697114321001013210410111697115116101321119910432109101115116321111091151071141051181109732107228110100105115971143210611711511632110117321091011003211012110410111610111444329810510810010111432111991043211810510010111111546346260471091011169762109601081051101073211410110861349711211210810145116111117991044510599111110343210411410110261344797112112108101451161111179910445105991111104611211010334626047108105110107621096010810511010732114101108613411510411111411699117116321059911111034321041141011026134471029711810599111110461059911134626047108105110107621096010810511010732114101108613499971101111101059997108343210411410110261341041161161125847471191191194611211111510450524611510147107971101001051159711434626047108105110107621096010810511010732114101108613497108116101114110971161013432116121112101613497112112108105999711610511111047114115115431201091083432104114101102613447102101101100343211610511610810161347522811010010511532111991043211024610610111511012110410111610111432102114229110328011111510450523462604710810511010762106010810511010732104114101102613447471021111101161154610311111110310810197112105115469911110947991151156310297109105108121617911210111043839711011558524848445248481051169710810599445548484455484810511697108105993432114101108613411511612110810111510410110111634321161211121016134116101120116479911511534476210999601081051101073210411410110261344747109971209910011046981111111161151161149711299100110469911110947981111111161151161149711247514650464847991151154798111111116115116114971124610910511046991151153432114101108613411511612110810111510410110111634321161211121016134116101120116479911511534324762109999601081051101073210411410110261349911511547110101119115469911511563112505211861535534321141011086134115116121108101115104101101116343211612111210161341161011201164799115115343247621091010999601159911410511211632116121112101613411610112011647106971189711599114105112116343211511499613447479710697120461031111111031081019711210511546991111094797106971204710810598115471061131171011141214749464950465247106113117101114121461091051104610611534626047115991141051121166210910999601159911410511211632116121112101613411610112011647106971189711599114105112116343211511499613447471099712099100110469811111111611511611497112991001104699111109479811111111611511611497112475146504648471061154798111111116115116114971124610910511046106115346260471159911410511211662109109996011599114105112116321161211121016134116101120116471069711897115991141051121163432115114996134115991141051121161154711010111911545109105110461061156311250521186153553462604711599114105
2020-01-22 15:37:29.458 1406-1755/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2020-01-22 15:37:29.461 3937-4045/com.example.guessthecelebrity D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2020-01-22 15:37:29.480 1398-1437/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 20 syncs in 86s
2020-01-22 15:37:29.534 1397-1397/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496`

What I need to do?

Comment: Check that page for compression like Gzip. You have to handle the compression(if it is there).

Comment: I tried with some other websites too, but I keep having same problem. I don't think it is related with Gzip.

Comment: go to https://www.giftofspeed.com/gzip-test/ and check the compression. There is gzip compression enabled by server.

Comment: Okay, thanks to you. Now I know that it is because of gzip. But how can I handle it?

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved it. As you can see at the line 18 "result += data;" is wrong. I changed it with "result += current;" so I can get the HTML documents.